# Solidity smart contract: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am exploring ethereum and smart contract development in solidity. In a simple todo application smart contract, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

My code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract ToDo {
  struct Task{
    uint id;
    uint date;
    string content;
    string author;
    bool completed;
  }

  Task[] tasks;

  function createTask(string memory _content, string memory _author) public {
    tasks.push(Task(tasks.length, block.timestamp, _content, _author, false));
  }

  function getTask(uint id) public view 
    returns(
      uint,
      uint,
      string memory,
      string memory,
      bool
   ) {
     return(
       id,
       tasks[id].date,
       tasks[id].content,
       tasks[id].author,
       tasks[id].completed
     );
   }

   function getAllTasks() external view returns(Task[]){
     return tasks;
   }
}
```

Error lines are 20 and 21 In the getTask() function which is trying to return string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to the original question

Strings in Solidity are internally processed as arrays of characters, and you need to specify the data location of the return value for dynamic values such as arrays (see picture below).

[image: Solidity docs image]

That is because Solidity, as a language, was based on C++ and JS.

Also, the ("official") Solidity compiler and associated utilities are written in C++, and you don't have strings in C nor C++. just arrays of chars, so that might be the reason why strings in solidity are processed as arrays of characters.

```
  ...

  // You should consider using "blockchain.timestamp" instead of "now".
  function createTask(string memory _content, string memory _author) public {
    tasks.push(Task(tasks.length, now, _content, _author, false));
  }

  function getTask(uint id) public view 
    returns(
      uint,
      uint,
      string memory,
      string memory,
      bool
   ) {
     return(
       id,
       tasks[id].date,
       tasks[id].content,
       tasks[id].author,
       tasks[id].completed  // Also, removed the comma here because it would drop an empty tuple error.
     );
   }
   
   ...
```

### Answering the newer question

`TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder.`

Make sure to add `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` on top of your code, since [solidity versions under 0.8.0 don't support dynamic arrays with a depth level deeper than 1 by default, and you'll need to enable the experimental ABI for it to work](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58698/typeerror-this-type-is-only-supported-in-the-new-experimental-abi-encoder), for example, arrays of arrays, or in your case, an array of structs.

Comment: Okay, but still having error of same like "Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given."

Comment: @Neelgorasiya Can you post a screenshot of your error and code?. I've tried the mentioned solution using http://remix.ethereum.org/ and it compiles and deploys fine.

Comment: This is a different error you're having now, it seems that versions of solidity under 0.8.0 doesn't use the V2 of the ABI encoder (which supports arbitrarily levels of nested arrays, in this case the struct array which interally is processed as an array of arrays). So there's two solutions for that, you can either add "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" on top of your current code, or use solidity 0.8.X version, also, mind specifying your solidity compiler version on your truffle config, since by default it will use the truffle's version: http://i.prntscr.com/w50AcCbxTeeKADGLpDlvOQ.png .

Comment: You're welcome, yet, please consider closing the question (validating the answer or else) .